# Total variation distance between original and perturbed stationary distributions of Markov chain

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

Let us consider a Markov chain with transition probability $P$, such that this Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic, with stationary distribution $\pi$. Now, let us consider another transition probability $Q$ on the same state space, such that the resulting Markov chain is also irreducible and aperiodic, with stationary distribution $\mu$. We start from the same initial state distribution $d$. Assuming that $P$ and $Q$ are close to each other in some sense, is there anything we can say about the distance between $\pi$ and $\mu$, for example in total variation?

My initial take was to use a triangle inequality on that distance to write something like (informally):

$$
||\pi - \mu|| \leq ||\pi - P^td|| + ||P^td - Q^td|| + ||Q^td - \mu||
$$

for any $t$. The first and the last term can be bounded using a convergence theorem, but I can't really see anything interesting to say about the second term.

Thanks!

Comment: In what sense would $P$ and $Q$ be close to each other?

Comment: Interesting question, quite open-ended. In total variation for example.

Comment: I am only familiar with total variation distance in the context of probability measures or distributions. What would "total variation" mean for two stochastic matrices?

Comment: I would say L1 distance between these matrices.